# Help please - PHP Warning: include(Extendware/EWCore/Model/Autoload.php): failed to open stream:

Tags: magento-1.9

Due to a hack we needed to remove a module, we removed all files but we still have a 500 error. See below. I already removed the recourse in the database and also I turned off compilation through includes/config.php

```
PHP Warning:  include(Extendware/EWCore/Model/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 68
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'Extendware/EWCore/Model/Autoload.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/local:/var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/community:/var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core:/var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 68
PHP Warning:  include(Extendware/EWCore/Model/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'Extendware/EWCore/Model/Autoload.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/local:/var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/community:/var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core:/var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Extendware_EWCore_Model_Autoload' not found in /var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/code/local/Varien/Autoload.php on line 14
```

I even get these errors when I want to clear compilation or run the index throughs hell php -f compiler.php clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue, the module is called through below path / file

app/code/local/Varien/Autoload.php

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error your getting, it looks like the module is still registered within magento. Check for the configuration file.

In the directory:

```
app/etc/modules/
```

Look out for a file which has registered probably Extendaware_*.xml there might be more than one of them which will need to be disabled/removed.

When you complete this be sure to clear your cache to update the configuration.

Comment: no sorry that's not the issue.